# Counting large data based on specific filter in mongo in loopback 3

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a model A which has 3 fields {"name" : Name, "creationDate" : Date, "completionDate" : Date}, I want to get the count of all the data whose completion Date is less than today.

I have tried  filtering using Model.find(query) but it takes lot of time is there any efficient way in loopback3?

Comment: may be this one help you https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/improving-mongodb-performance-with-automatically-generated-index-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the count query?
Like:

```
YourModel.count({ 'completionDate' {'lt': yourDate} }, function (err, count) {
    if (!err)
         console.log(count);
});
```

If the query is still too long, try adding an index in `/common/models/yourModel.json`, like:

```
{
  "name": "YourModel",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "completionDate": {
      "type": "Date",
      "index": true
    }
...
}
```

And don't forget too add an autoupdate boot script file in `/server/boot/autoupdate.js`, containing:

```
'use strict';

var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function (server) {

    Promise.each(server.models(), function (model) {

        if (model.dataSource) {
            var autoupdate = Promise.promisify(model.dataSource.autoupdate);
            if (autoupdate) {
                return autoupdate.call(model.dataSource, model.modelName);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

to make sure your indexes are updated in your database!